# Google sites: How to edit the title tag of a page

Tags: google-sites

I created a site in the new Google site with just one page. I'd like to change the title tag so it s name is correctly displayed in search engines. The title of my page is "home"

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To find it:

1. Select the `Pages` tab in the right column
2. Hove over the page you want to change the title, a triple point icon will appear at the right
3. click on the triple point and the change the page name. It'll be the new page title.

The option is hidden in desktop and impossible to find in a mobile device.

It looks like there's no relation to which page is the home page.

If your site has more than one page, you'll probably also need to update all the links to it.